# running command ''tput' cols' had status 2

Tags: r

I get this warning whenever I start R. What does it mean and should I be concerned?

```
Warning message:
In system2("tput", "cols", stdout = TRUE) :
  running command ''tput' cols' had status 2
```

Comment: Are you using RStudio? If so, do you have script files you leave open in the source pane? Does the environment pane reflect multiple objects? I'm going to guess one or the other (or both) is true. There is likely something among these elements causing you to see this error. Try clearing out the environment pane and source pane, then restart the R session. See if the issue persists.

Comment: Are you using RStudio? No; do you have script files you leave open in the source pane? No; Does the environment pane reflect multiple objects? Im not sure about this. How would I check? Try clearing out the environment pane and source pane, then restart the R session. How would I do this? The problem has persistent for a long time. literally every time I start up R after quitting. It has even persistent across reinstallation of R.

Comment: If you're not using RStudio, then the other questions won't make sense. Do you use R directly? Or do you use a different IDE, like Atom? For status 2, it means that 'Usage error; `tput` was given invalid arguments.' When is the last time you updated R? Did it persist after the update (if it was somewhat recent)? What OS are you running?

Comment: One other thing to try--remove the package `data.table`. Restart R, is it there? You can re-add it if it stops, the update should fix it if that's the source.

Comment: I use Sublime text so not an IDE as such.

Comment: I last updated R 2 days ago and the issue persistent between updates. The issue has been with me for a very long time.

Comment: I am run macosx/

Comment: How would I go about removing data.table?

Comment: I removed data.tabel with remove.packages() and the message is still there on restart. I should add I slaps get the message "tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified" in addition to the aforementioned messages.